# Condition on degree to ensure that a generic line bundle of that degree is very ample

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be any smooth genus $g\geq 1$ curve (exclude $g=1$ as well if you want). What is the smallest possible integer $d$ to make the following statement correct: "A general line bundle $L$ of degree $\geq d$ on $C$ is very ample." ?

Can we improve the bound $d$ by assuming that $C$ is not hyperelliptic?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ample_line_bundle#Criteria_for_ampleness_of_line_bundles implies that we can take $d = 2g + 1$ in general and $d = 2g - 2$ if $C$ is not hyperelliptic.

Comment: Yes, but this is not what my question is about. All line bundles of degree $\geq 2g+1$ are indeed very ample, but I am not asking for all line bundles having this property, only(!) the "generic" one.